# Segmentation fault when accessing C string in Ada

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, ada

I am trying to access a string declared in a C program from an Ada subprogram, but I get a segmentation fault. Would anyone be able to help me fix this?

Here's an example of what fails, it seems that the segfault comes from the call to `Interfaces.C.Strings.Value` in ada_decs.adb, but I'm not sure why, or how I can make it work.

The backtrace from gdb shows:

```
#0  0x00000000004167ea in system.secondary_stack.ss_mark ()
#1  0x00000000004037e6 in ada_print_it (s=0x427244 "Hello") at (...)/ada_decs.adb:2
#2  0x000000000040327c in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe568) at (...)/main.c:5
```

(with `(...)` signifying the full file path).

ada_decs.ads:

```
with Interfaces.C.Strings;
with Ada.Text_IO;
package Ada_Decs is
    procedure Print_It (s : Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr) with
        Export => True,
        Convention => C,
        External_Name => "ada_print_it";
end Ada_Decs;
```

ada_decs.adb:

```
package body Ada_Decs is
    procedure Print_It (s : Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr) is
        str : String := Interfaces.C.Strings.Value(s);
    begin
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(str);
    end Print_It;
end Ada_Decs;
```

main.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
extern void ada_print_it (const char *s);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  const char *hello = "Hello";
  ada_print_it(hello);
}
```

Comment: `chars_ptr` corresponds to `char*`, not to `const char *`, although this is unlikely to be a problem here.

Comment: I thought so as well so I tried both, but didn't make a difference in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a main program written in C, you need to allow the Ada RTS to initialise itself before you can use any of its functionality. And shut itself down on exit.

The `adainit()` and `adafinal()` calls will do this.

```
extern void adainit (void);
extern void adafinal (void);    

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

   adainit();

   const char *hello = "Hello";
   ada_print_it(hello);

   adafinal();
}
```

For a main program written in Ada. this is taken care of automatically by the binder, Gnatbind.

You may also need to add linker arguments to let the linker find these RTS functions : see the [Gnat documents](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gnat_ugn/) (chapter 3.11, Mixed Language interfacing) for more details. There's a worked example [at the bottom of this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gnat_ugn/Interfacing-to-C.html#Interfacing-to-C).

Both links for gcc9.3; other gcc versions may differ a little so check the correct documentation.

Comment: Perfect, that worked for me. No linker arguments were needed, it was enough to declare them as `extern`. Thank you!